# How do I set my Android Nexus 4 via bluetooth MAP to get messages in car

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4 and I am trying to get it to work with my car computer, and for most parts via Bluetooth it works, especially for audio. I cant get the text messaging part to work, and that has to do with MAP profile for bluetooth.

When I had a samsung SIII it worked, but for some reason, with this it doesnt seem to work.. I heard from someone that it may be an issue and you need to install a custom rom. Is that true? Is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 1):

It was broken in 4.2 when Google rewrote the Bluetooth stack.

Answer (score 0):

MAP was never implemented in AOSP, the SIII only had it from Samsung tweaks.